# port 22: Connection refused after sudo reboot in AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2

After Rebooting AWS instance from ssh, it shows port 22: Connection refused.
Got many solution like  need to change in sshd file, but again my question is how to change that file without connecting to server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detach the volume and attach it to another instance, mount it, fix the sshd configuration and then attach it back again to the original instance.

Note that you will have to stop and start that instance. However, you won't need to stop the instance where you attach the disk.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you are adding the username and "@" before public DNS : **ubuntu@**

```
ssh -i abcdefg.pem.txt ubuntu@<public DNS of your instance>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a really simple solution to this problem. Go to your AWS right-click on your instance and select Reboot instance. Hope this solve your problem.

Comment: This solved it. Went to the console and rebooted. Gave it a couple of minutes and now I can ssh back in. Thank you!